# How label a cnn in keras and use mse metrics

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, mse

I have to train a cnn using as loss function mse.
I normalized the labels between  0-1 but when I train I get

> expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (7,)

The last layer is 
`x = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)`

and when I compile and train:

```py
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),metrics=['mse'])


model_details=model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Comment: Could you include your code? Or at least the part where you build your model?

Comment: what is `Y_train.shape`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resized the Y_train matrix to 1D vector: each component of the vector is the label to the respective image.